# How to Solve Recurrence Relations When Master Theorem is not Applicable

Tags: algorithm, recursion, math, time-complexity, recurrence

How to mathematically solve the recurrence relations of the following form :

1. [T(n)=(2^n)T(n/2) + n^n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GAIA.png)
2. [T(n)=4T(n/2) + n^(2)/logn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Yfa4.gif)

Is there a generic method to solve these?

I realize that master theorem is not applicable on these forms because in 1, 2^n is not a constant and 2 does not fall into any of the 3 cases of the master theorem.

Comment: #1 is unusual as recurrences go in practice; suspect it's just Theta(n^n) however. #2 will be Theta(n^2 log^2 n) by Akra–Bazzi.

Comment: The second one can be solved with the [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), as David mentions. I don't know of a generic method for the first one besides strong induction, which would show that it's Theta(n^n). However, that's closer to a pure math question than a programming question, so you'll get a more helpful answer at the [math Stackexchange site](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Actually I had made an error while posting the 2nd Recurrence Relation. I had written n^2 logn instead of n^2/logn
I found out that former is solvable by Master Theorem but the latter is not. My question is about the latter

Comment: Akra-Bazzi still applies to the new second equation, but gives `Theta(n^2 log(log(n)))` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing a path base as n = 2^m we have the recurrence

T(2^m) = 2^(2^m)T(2^(m-1)) + (2^m)^(2^m)

Calling now TT(.) = T(2^(.)) we follow with

TT(m) = 2^(2^m)TT(m-1) + (2^m)^(2^m)

This is a linear recurrence easily solved as

TT(m) = 4^(2^m-2)(c0 + sum[2^(4-2^(k+2))*(2^(k+1))^(2^(k+1)),(k,0,m-1)])

now going backwards with m = log(2,n) we get at

T(n) = 4^(n-2)(c0 + sum[2^(4-2^(k+2))*(2^(k+1))^(2^(k+1)),(k,0,log(2,n)-1)])

or

T(n) = 4^(n-2)c0 + n^n + 2^(n/2)n^(n/2) + ... +

The second recurrence can be solved following the same process.